# How to change the affine transform of an object dynamically using 4x4 transformation matrix.(float array of 16 elements)

Tags: iphone, transformation, unity-game-engine

Hi i need to transform an object dynamically in Unity iphone project using the float array of 16 which will be generated using ARToolKit. what is the api in unity 3d to change trasformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `GameObjec`t in Unity has a `Transform` component attached to it.  This can be accessed from other components using

```
Transform trans = gameObject.transform
```

This component has properties that can be used to alter the object's transformation. Among them are e.g.

```
position (Vector3)
rotation (Quaternion)
eulerAngles (Vector3)
localScale (Vector3)
...
```

You should be able to pull values out of your 4x4 matrix and apply them to these properties. I don't think there's a way to directly apply a matrix to a GameObject.

Comment: For UI objects you have to use `TransformRect` instead.